# Visible light communication using photodiode receiver

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, transimpedance-amplifier

I am designing a receiver circuit using photodiode with visible light communication application, analog signal I read with ADC of esp8266.

The circuit below is my design with a TIA and amplifier. Is there a bug?

I want to catch the light with 1-7 kHz frequency.

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 5):

> Don't know if there is a bug

There are at least two.

1. When working properly, the output voltage of U2B will be negative. But U2 can't produce negative outputs without a negative power supply.
2. U2A is working as a comparator, but the range of reference voltages provided by VR1 is 0 to 5 V. Comparing this with the negative output voltage of U2B will always result in a low output.

Comment: Can you help me fix this design completely, I don't know too much about this knowledge

Comment: @Shu, I would re-design the first stage to one of the cofigurations that doesn't generate a negative output.

Comment: I found this design in another project, somehow it still works well and the result is quite workable.

Comment: How not to produce negative output at U2B